# Have Scalatra exit if LifeCycle added with Context.setInitParameter throws exception

Tags: scala, jetty, scalatra

I want a Scalatra servlet to exit if initialization fails so that upstart/systemd/whatever can restart it on failure.

Drawing from examples on the web, we have a `LifeCycle` that does some initialization, but occasionally fails

```scala
class Bootstrap extends LifeCycle {
  override def init(context: ServletContext) {
    throw new RunTimeException("foo")
  }
}
```

Our initialization procedure is otherwise pretty typical

```scala
val server = new Server(port)
val context = new WebAppContext()
context setContextPath("/")
context.setResourceBase("src/lab/src/main/webapp")
context.setInitParameter(ScalatraListener.LifeCycleKey, "Bootstrap")

context.addEventListener(new ScalatraListener)
server.setHandler(context)

server.start
server.join
```

Is there a way to make the server stop on an initialization exception without putting a try block around the bootstrap code and calling `stop` manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The slightly longer answer is that your LifeCycle (ScalatraBootstrap) init is already wrapped in a try/catch block, you can see that in the [source for ScalatraListener](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/2.4.x/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/servlet/ScalatraListener.scala#L25). But it just throws an exception.

There's two reasons for this;

First -- The bootstrap is designed to bootstrap more than one servlet, if one fails, the expected condition is the rest still come up.

Second -- even if you only stand up one servlet, the reason your shutdown code isn't called is actually defined in the servlet spec;

> 2.3.2.1 Error Conditions on Initialization
>
> During initialization, the servlet instance can throw an
>   UnavailableException or a ServletException. In this case, the servlet
>   must not be placed into active service and must be released by the
>   servlet container. The destroy method is not called as it is
>   considered unsuccessful initialization.